# @Component vs new operator in java

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

I am new to Spring concept, so I have little confusion about `@Component` which by default is a singleton which creates an instance whenever a class is loaded and the same instance is reused; same happens with new operator. If a class is declared as singleton we can change the properties of the class using setters and getters same with new operator also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `new` , you are creating the instance during runtime manually.

Assume , you have a controller being called 'N' number of times which im turn calls a Service.

**Java**

In plain java, you will be creating a New Object by calling `new`. Which means , you are creating 'n'number of objects

**Spring**

In Spring, when you just deploy the application in the server or load the spring `XML/Configuration class`, the Spring creates an instances of all the classes which are annotated , and stores in the spring container. Now,even if your controller is called 'n'times, spring will use the same object again and again
Because you wont call `new` instead use another annotation called **Autowired**

Answer (score 1):

@Component annotation says that the object is managed by Spring: i.e. the framework creates it. Usually you should use the dependenci injection mechanism using Spring: I mean you don't need to create the component instance by yourself but inject the provided one into your code.
Read about the IoC paradigm here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control

Also you can actually change the scope of the Spring managed bean to different then singleton ([see tutorial here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-bean-scopes-examples/)) but if you already implenemted some singleton class on your own you can't override it's behavior

BTW you shouldn't use the **new** operator for singletons (actually you can't because of private constructor), use method like *getInstance()* instead

Comment: Spring takes care of creating the instance, but my question when the scope is singleton an object is created only once and it can be reused same thing happens with the new operator that means an object is created using new operator and it  can be used in further application.. so whats the difference in functionality ?

Comment: @Componennt is for inversion of control: i.e. object is not created in your code but provided from the outside (in this case by Spring) and so it can be replaced by Spring. If you implement singleton in pure Java - your code is tightly dependent on that particular object